# Custom seekbar with meter units as background like scale

Tags: android, view, scale, android-custom-view, android-seekbar

[image: Like this seekbar]

I want to implement seekbar like this , it should have units lines as background
Please help me ... Thanks in advance

Comment: create a custom `Drawable` class and use it with `SeekBar#setProgressDrawable()` call

Comment: can you provide some example?

Comment: example of how to extend some class?

Comment: no. seekbar drawable

Comment: `class SeekBarDrawable extends Drawable { ...`

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am looking for same thing.